# Calculate the number of days since the creation date of a user account

Tags: users, datetime

I would like to calculate the number of days past since a users creation date. This is what I have done so far:

```
$user = \Drupal::currentUser();
$registrationdate = getdate($user->getCreatedTime());
$today = getdate();
$daypast = date_diff($regdate, $today);
```

This results in the following error:

> date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface

How can I solve this and get the number of days past since the users registration date?

Comment: Guess I could point out the obvious. Your variables are wrong. Not $regdate it is $registrationdate.

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of [calculate time between dates](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/149442/calculate-time-between-start-and-end-time), there is a nice solution, look on comments, there is a link to a youtube demo. it needs rules module.

Comment: @Brady comment explains the error message, while mpdonadio answer explains the Drupal code to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on what you need to do with it.  If you truly just need the number of days, then this will work

```
$user = \Drupal::currentUser();
$created = new \DateTime('@' . $user->getAccount()->getCreatedTime());
$interval = $created->diff(new \DateTime());
$days1 = $interval->d
$days2 = intval($interval->format('%d'));
```

Here `$days1` and `$days2` should give you the same value.  See the docs for [`\DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`\DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) for more information.

If you need a nifty string for output purposes, then check out [`DateFormatter::formatTimeDiffSince()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DateFormatter.php/function/DateFormatter%3A%3AformatTimeDiffSince/8.2.x) and friends:

```
$user = \Drupal::currentUser();
$created = $user->getAccount()->getCreatedTime();
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatterInterface $date_formatter */
$date_formatter = \Drupal::service('date.formatter');
$created_since = $date_formatter->formatTimeDiffSince($created);
```

and then `$created_since` will be a string like '7 weeks 2 days'.  You can also use the 'Time ago' formatter directly in the entity rendering configuration.  The default view for the accounts listing does this.

Comment: +1 for `DateFormatter::formatTimeDiffSince()`. I doubt the OP would want to show the difference in days when a year is past. _700 days ago_ is not much helpful.

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of calculate time between dates, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/149442/calculate-time-between-start-and-end-time, there is a nice solution, look on comments, there is a link to a youtube demo. it needs rules module.